# react, styled-components - setting props on a imported styled div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to write a react component where I can load different styled div-s according to passed props and render them. This is my code so far:

Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import s, { keyframes } from "styled-components";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import { jumpyRotation } from "../animations/jumpyRotation.js";
import { normalRotation } from "../animations/normalRotation.js";

import { baseShape } from "../shapes/base";

const animations = {
  jumpyRotation: jumpyRotation,
  normalRotation: normalRotation
};

const shapes = {
  square: baseShape
};

class Loader extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      size = "14px",
      color = "#000",
      fontSize = "14px",
      loaderText = "Loading...",
      length = "4s",
      animation = "jumpyRotation",
      shape = "square"
    } = this.props;

    const styledShape = shapes[shape];

    styledShape.attrs.size = size;
    styledShape.attrs.color = color;
    styledShape.attrs.animation = animation;
    styledShape.attrs.length = length;

    return (
      <LoaderStyles
        length={length}
        animation={animations[animation]}
        fontSize={fontSize}
        color={color}
        size={size}
      >
        styledShape
        <span className="loader-text">{loaderText}</span>
      </LoaderStyles>
    );
  }
}

Loader.propTypes = {
  size: PropTypes.string, // Size in a valid CSS unit
  color: PropTypes.string, // A valid CSS color, changes both loader and text
  fontSize: PropTypes.string, // Size in a valid CSS unit
  loaderText: PropTypes.string, // Text displayed under the loader
  length: PropTypes.string, // The length of animation in a valid CSS unit
  animation: PropTypes.string // The name of the animation
};

const LoaderStyles = s.div`
  font-size: ${props => props.fontSize};
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: ${props => props.fontSize};
  .loader-text {
    color: ${props => props.color};
  }
`;

export default Loader;
```

Styled component `../shapes/base`:

```
import s from "styled-components";

export const baseShape = s.div`
  margin: ${props => props.size};
  height: ${props => props.size};
  width: ${props => props.size};
  background-color: ${props => props.color};
  animation: ${props => props.animation} ${props =>
  props.length} linear infinite;
`;
```

Now according to the [styled component docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api), using the syntax should work, but I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'size' of undefined

Even though the browser debugger shows styledShape as a styled.div

Comment: Why you have written ```import s```, shouldn't  it ```import styled```,is that a typo because I didn't found any ```s``` in API reference,& also the error means that your object doesn't contain any attribute of name ```size```.that also shows that you might have imported a wrong object and trying to acess such attributes which doesn't exists.

Comment: @VinitRaj `import` without `{}` is just giving a name to the default export from the module/package, it can be named whatever you like, although I would agree that the norm is `styled`

Comment: Would it be possible to define the attrs from scratch? `const attrs = {size, color, animation, length};`
`styledShape.attrs = {attrs}`

Comment: @cadmiun tried `styledShape.attrs({
      size,
      color,
      animation,
      length
    });` , but getting styledShape.attrs is not a function. Will probably try to write a workaround.

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič set `const {...... //your content goes here} = this.props` before the render block

Answer (score 0):

React only recognizes components if they start with capital letters, so the solution was this (omitted irrelevant code from the anwser):

Styled component:

```
import s from "styled-components";

export const baseShape = s.div`
  margin: ${Brops => props.size};
  height: ${props => props.size};
  width: ${props => props.size};
  background-color: ${props => props.color};
  animation: ${props => props.animation} ${props =>
  props.length} linear infinite;
`;
```

Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import s from "styled-components";

import { BaseShape } from "../shapes/base";

const shapes = {
  square: BaseShape
};

class Loader extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      size,
      color,
      animation,
      shape
    } = this.props;

    const ShapeDiv = shapes[shape];

    return (
      <ShapeDiv size={size} color={color} animation={animation} shape={shape}/>
    );
  }
}

export default Loader;
```